# If Z is regularly varying with index $\alpha$, then $zP(Z>z)$ is decreasing

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

i want to show: if $Z\geq0$ is regularly varying with index $\alpha$, that the function $zP(Z>z)$ is decreasing.

Def: A randomvariable $Z$ is regularly varying with index $\alpha>1$ if for all $t>0$

$\lim_{x\longrightarrow\infty}\frac{P(Z>tx)}{P(Z>x)}=t^{-\alpha}$

I tried to use the definition of an increasing function, but got stuck because i dont know where i can use the assumption, that $Z$ is reg.varying.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math. stackexchange. This is a nicely formulated problem, and your attempt to solve it is clear. However, this statement cannot be correct. Consider **any** positive random variable $Z_0$, for example a regularly varying one. Now choose $M > 0$ and set $Z = Z_0+M$. Then $P(Z > z) = 1$ for all $z < M$ and therefore $zP(Z > z) =  z$, which is strictly increasing on this interval.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! I understand your example, but im not sure, whether $Z=Z_0+M$ is regularly varying?

Comment: If $Z_0$ is chosen to be regularly varying, then $Z$ is also regularly varying, since this is a condition about the limiting behavior of the tail distribution of $Z$.

Comment: Got it, thank you!